# xsbt 0.10.x using xsbt-web-plugin fails to find org.eclipse.jetty during build

Tags: scala, jetty, sbt, embedded-jetty

This used to work with sbt 0.7 using a web plugin.

I'm only trying to compile a servlet, but a standalone embedded jetty would be fine as well.

> value eclipse is not a member of package org [error] import
>
> _root_.org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.{  WebSocket  , WebSocketServlet }

Note that *root* was added because it fixed a similar error with sbt 0.7.x getting lost in a conflicting packaged path.

in my `build.sbt` I have (only need distribution probably)

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq (
    "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-distribution" % "7.4.5.v20110725" % "jetty"
    , "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "7.4.5.v20110725" % "jetty"
    , "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-http" % "7.4.5.v20110725" % "jetty"
    , "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-server" % "7.4.5.v20110725" % "jetty"
    , "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-io" % "7.4.5.v20110725" % "jetty"
    , "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-util" % "7.4.5.v20110725" % "jetty"
    , "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-websocket" % "7.4.5.v20110725" % "jetty"
    , "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-continuation" % "7.4.5.v20110725" % "jetty"
)
```

The file that fails to compile has

```
package org.example

import _root_.javax.servlet.http._
import _root_.org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.{  WebSocket  , WebSocketServlet }

...

class Home extends WebSocketServlet { 

...
```

[edit] - removed directory structure info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependencies in the `jetty` configuration are only used to run Jetty itself and are not put on the classpath for compilation.  For the Jetty libraries to be available on the compilation classpath, use either the `compile` or `provided` configuration.  `compile` puts the libraries on all classpaths, while `provided` only puts them on the compile (and test) classpath.

In this case, you probably want `provided,jetty`.  This makes the Jetty jars available to the web plugin for running Jetty (the `jetty` part) as well as putting Jetty on your compilation classpath (the `provided` part).

For example, the websocket dependency would look like:

```
"org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-websocket" % "7.4.5.v20110725" % "provided,jetty"
```